# Using a button to check if EditText is empty

Tags: java, android

I have a registration page for an android app which requires the user to enter an email address, and their name. I have a button on the same page which they click to register, I need this button to check if these entry fields are empty. If they are, then display an error explaining, if not, for an alert to appear thanking them etc, then have the app close. I have tried many different methods, many using ".isEmpty".

Comment: there is no magic. you should implement relevant code to make it happen. let others know what exactly your question is - including what you have tried and how it didn't work out. you can't just expect people to write code for you.

Comment: Please, add some code examples of what You have tried, it will make the question clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java code:

```
if(tvName.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
{
   //Show dialog or toast to notify to user
}
```

You can do the same thing to check empty for the text view of email.

Comment: @Golcarjack. If my answer was right in your problem, please mark it as accepted answer. Thank you!